# eccentricity of ellipse using two defintions

Tags: conic-sections

Eccentricity is defined in terms of directrix as:$$e = \dfrac{PS}{PM}$$

Also eccentricity has a formula $$e=\dfrac{c}{a}$$
where $c$ is distance between center and focus
$a$ is the length of semi major axis.
How are these two equivalent? Looks some symmetric triangles are involved, but I don't see them. Any help?

[image]

Comment: @FareedAbiFarraj Exactly what I need. Thank you so much:)

Comment: Your welcome :)